# ASP.NET: Page HTML head rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to figure out the best way to custom render the `<head>` element of a page to get rid of the extra line breaks which is caused by `<head runat="server">`, so its properly formatted.

So far the only thing i've found which works is the following:

```
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        base.Render(htmlTextWriter);
        htmlTextWriter.Close();
        string html = stringWriter.ToString();
        string newHTML = html.Replace("<title>\r\n\t", "<title>")
                             .Replace("\r\n</title>", "</title>")
                             .Replace("</head>", "\n</head>");

        writer.Write(newHTML);
    }
```

Now i have 2 questions:

1. How does the above code affect the performance (so is this viable in a production environment)?
2. Is there a better way to do this, for example a method which i can override to just custom render the `<head>`?

Oh yeah ASP.NET MVC is not an option.

**EDIT:**

Im asking this with regards to SEO and just little bit perfectionism.

Comment: why do you want to get rid of the extra lines break ?

Comment: This perfectionism applied to markup code in particular will only lead to your prolonged suffering.

Comment: A few extra line breaks mean nothing since the whitespace is collapsed when rendered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my experience, using ASP.NET Forms implies an irrevocable surrender of control over your HTML output.  It is better to accept the following:

- Microsoft form controls will sometimes use depreciated or flat-out wrong HTML.
- The Viewstate tag will always be there, even when ViewState is disabled at the page or site level.  Apparently, there needs to be a ViewState to tell ASP.NET that there isn't a view state.
- You are **not** in control of form elements.  There will be one form element per page, and it belongs to ASP.NET.
- JavaScript will be used to perform even rudimentary tasks.  The JavaScript will be unreadable, directly embedded in your page, and at least 50% of it will be extraneous.
- You will not be able to create page fragments, unless you do it through a web service and a lot of kludge.  Each .aspx page will have `<html>` `<head>` and almost always `<form>` tags.

If you want fine control over your page output, using MVC or another framework is all but mandatory.  Even classic ASP will work, but not ASP.NET Forms.

Comment: +1 So either switch framework/language or stop caring. Gonna wait a bit with marking this as answer to see if i can get some more input. Thanks!